# Laravel: Why isn't the query result showing in my view?

Tags: laravel-5

I am successfully getting results in/from my controller like this:

`$session_id` and `$user_id` are getting passed into my method.

**Controller**

```
// get all sets belonging to the user for the given session
$session = Session::findOrFail($session_id);
$sets = Set::where('session_id', $session_id)->where('user_id', $user_id);    
$user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

return View('users.index')
    ->with('session', $session)            
    ->with('sets', $sets)
    ->with('user', $user);
```

**View**

```
<p>{{ $user->first_name }} has {{ $sets->count() }} existing set{{ ($sets->count() > 1 ? 's': '') }}.</p>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    @foreach ($sets as $set)
        <li>
            <a href="{{ ur('/sessions/'.$session->id.'/user/'.$user->id.'/long-snap/set/'.$set->id) }}">Set</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I am seeing "Foo has 1 existing set." and I can see the record in the DB. However, I'm not getting into the loop at all. If I add/remove records, my paragraph text updates accordingly as well - but I still never get into the loop to show each set. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I sure don't see it.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Just dd($user) before returning the view and show me the output. Also you have not written whole query of sets you have to get() or first() method to get collection or array @Damon

Comment: Doing `dd()` was giving me back the object, but as you pointed out it was the `get()` I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: It was pleasure to help you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query of sets to this:

```
$sets = Set::where('session_id', $session_id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

As `get()` method will return you the collection object.

Comment: SEE I KNEW IT WAS SOMETHING OBVIOUS! :) Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @Damon!